# Importing file from another folder to an Intellij-idea project without copying it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Python project in IntelliJ-Idea.
I would like to import a remote file into my project, **without copying it into the project folder** (but it should be just listed in idea)

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you want a file be listed inside a project, the project need to contains the file. So I don't think it's possible with intellij.
Maybe with a symlink inside your system ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the remote file by adding a content root to your module.

See `Project Structure > Modules > 'YourModule' > +Add Content Root`

This will include the 'other' content in your project without physically copying the other content into your project.

Note: you will of course need to be able to access the other content from within IntelliJ so by "remote" I presume you mean not located within your project directory but available on your host rather than something like 'available in a remote GitHub repo'.